# Using Also and as

Tags: conjunctions, commas

Can we write like this: "***Also as*** a result of the renormalization group procedure ***one layer*** is eliminated and the energy scale is reduced."

And do I need to put an comma before one layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can begin a sentence with "Also as". You can also begin it with "Also, as", which does not mean the same thing.

- > Also as a result of the renormalization group procedure, one layer is eliminated and the energy scale is reduced.

  The layer is eliminated as a result of the renormalization group procedure *and so is some other, aforementioned thing*. The comma before "one layer" is not strictly required and a matter of style. I personally would use it to break the sentence down and help the reader follow.
- > Also, as a result of the renormalization group procedure, one layer is eliminated and the energy scale is reduced.

  The result of the renormalization group procedure is *only* the layer's being eliminated and the energy scale's being reduced, *not* some aforementioned thing as well. The comma before "one layer" is obligatory, as it doubles up as the closing comma of the parenthetical "as a result of the renormalization group procedure".